# How can I extend quote's width in moderncv?

Tags: indentation, moderncv, quoting

How can I extend quote's width in moderncv? I want the quote element to be wider so it would occupy less amount of lines. Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,english]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[scale=0.8,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Calibri}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{Courier New}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Software Developer}
\mobile{mobile number}
\quote{\lipsum[11]}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,english]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[scale=0.8,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Calibri}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{Courier New}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Software Developer}
\mobile{mobile number}
\quote{\lipsum[11]}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\recomputecvlengths}{%
  \setlength{\quotewidth}{0.65\textwidth}%
}{%
  \setlength{\quotewidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
}{}{}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't really get it. What makes it work? An explanation would have made the answer look better.

Answer (score 11):

Lockstep didn´t worked for me.I am running Windows 7, Miktex and Texmaker.

This worked for me:

```
\let\originalrecomputecvlengths\recomputecvlengths
\renewcommand*{\recomputecvlengths}{%
\originalrecomputecvlengths%
\setlength{\quotewidth}{0.8\textwidth}}
```

i found that on https://answers.launchpad.net/moderncv/+question/210616

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Answers provided on this site tend to be more helpful if the code that's provided is not just a code snippet but a compilable [minimum working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001). Please consider modifying editing your posting to create such an MWE.

Comment: Great. This worked for me.